# How can I get this GIF from another website?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a website and I want a certain gif background that runs automatically on page load, here is the link of the website

http://contact-festival.com/

And I want to use the moving star-background on the artist line up list

I checked my developer tools and the network , but can't seem to find a source

Comment: Search on site's CSS file, probably it will be there the reference to the image.

Comment: It's drawn on `<canvas />`, which means you can't get it as GIF.

Comment: try this: http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Answer (score 4):

These are **not** `gifs` . **These are made with canvas tags and javascript coding**.

> So here is an example below that you can use.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  
  var element = "starfield";
  var bgColor = "#030304";
  var FPS = 30;
  var displacementRate = 5;
  var accelerationRate = 10;
  var maxSpeed = 100;
  var maxStars = 1000;

  
  var speedUp = setInterval(function(){
    if (accelerationRate > maxSpeed) {
     clearInterval(speedUp); 
    }
    accelerationRate = accelerationRate * 1.1;
  },100);

 var Star = function() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.z = 0;
  this.maxDepth = 0;
  this.alpha = 0;
  this.radius = 0;

  this.dx = 0;
  this.dy = 0;
  this.dz = 0;
  this.ddx = 0;
  this.ddy = 0;

  this.drawInContext = function(ctx, deltaX, deltaY) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255," + this.alpha + ")";
   ctx.arc(this.x + deltaX, this.y + deltaY, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
   ctx.fill();
  };
 };

 var requestAnimationFrame =  
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
   return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / FPS);
  };

 function isCanvasSupported(element) {
  return !!(element.getContext && element.getContext("2d"));
 }

 function backingScale(context) {
  if ('devicePixelRatio' in window) {
   if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
    return window.devicePixelRatio;
   }
  }

  return 1;
 }

 function StarField(canvasID) {
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  if (!isCanvasSupported(this.canvas)) {
   this.canvas.className = "inactive";
   this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   this.isCanvasEnabled = false;
   return this;
  }

  this.isCanvasEnabled = true;

  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.scaleFactor = backingScale(this.ctx);
  this.stars = new Array();

  function newStar() {
   var star = new Star();
   star.x = Math.random() * this.canvas.width - this.originX;
   star.y = Math.random() * this.canvas.height - this.originY;
   star.z = star.max_depth = Math.max(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
   star.alpha = Math.random();
   star.radius = Math.random();

   var xcoeff = star.x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
   var ycoeff = star.y > 0 ? 1 : -1;

   if (Math.abs(star.x) > Math.abs(star.y)) {
    star.dx = 1.0;
    star.dy = Math.abs(star.y / star.x);
   } else {
    star.dx = Math.abs(star.x / star.y);
    star.dy = 1.0;
   }

   star.dx *= xcoeff * (displacementRate / 10);
   star.dy *= ycoeff * (displacementRate / 10);
   star.dz = -1;

   star.ddx = (accelerationRate * star.dx) / 10;
   star.ddy = (accelerationRate * star.dy) / 10;

   return star;
  }

  function move(star) {
   star.x += star.dx;
   star.y += star.dy;
   star.z += star.dz;
 
   star.dx += star.ddx;
   star.dy += star.ddy;
  }

  function updateStars(ctx, stars) {
   for (var i=0; i<stars.length; i++) {
    move(stars[i]);

    if (stars[i].x < -this.originX || stars[i].x > this.originX || stars[i].y < -this.originY || stars[i].y > this.originY) {
     // Remove
     stars[i] = newStar();
    } else {
     // Paint
     var deltaX = this.originX;
     var deltaY = this.originY;
     stars[i].drawInContext(ctx, deltaX, deltaY);
    }
   }
  }

  this.configureGeometry = function() {
   // Ensure we are always at full width
   this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   this.canvas.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
   var ratio = 1;

   // Retina support
   // See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/
   if (this.scaleFactor > 1) {
    var devicePixelRatio = this.scaleFactor;
    var context = this.ctx;
    var backingStoreRatio = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;
    ratio = devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio;

    // Upscale the canvas if the two ratios don't match
    if (devicePixelRatio !== backingStoreRatio) {
     var canvas = this.canvas;
     var oldWidth = canvas.width;
     var oldHeight = canvas.height;

     canvas.width = oldWidth * ratio;
     canvas.height = oldHeight * ratio;

     canvas.style.width = oldWidth + 'px';
     canvas.style.height = oldHeight + 'px';

     // Now scale the context to counter the fact that we've manually scaled our canvas element
     context.scale(ratio, ratio);
    }
   }

   // Starting origin of stars
   var logicalWidth = this.canvas.width / ratio;
   var logicalHeight = this.canvas.height / ratio;

   this.originX = logicalWidth / 2;
   this.originY = logicalHeight / 2;

   var numStars = logicalWidth / 2;
   this.numStars = numStars > maxStars ? maxStars : numStars;
  }

  this.render = function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
    // Drawing
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    updateStars(this.ctx, this.stars);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

   }, 1000 / FPS);
  };

  // Configure origin and frames before creating initial batch of stars
  this.configureGeometry();

  for (var i=0; i<this.numStars; i++) {
   this.stars.push(newStar());
  }

  return this;
 }

 var starfield = StarField(element);
 if (starfield.isCanvasEnabled) {
  starfield.render();
 }

 // Make sure we adjust the canvas whenever the window resizes
 // Don't rely on CSS rules for 100% width because that causes rendering issues
 window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
 function resizeCanvas() {
  if (starfield.isCanvasEnabled) {
   starfield.configureGeometry();
  } else {
   starfield.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="starfield" width="100%" height="400px"></canvas>
```